# React.js: логика обработки модального окна

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, modal

Не могу понять, каким образом стоит отлавливать действия пользователя в модальном окне.

У меня есть родительский компонент, есть компонент модального окна и логическая функция. 
Логическая функция вызывает диалоговое модальное окно.

Задача (миссия невыполнима!) приостановить дальнейшее выполнение функции до получения фидбека от пользователя (как приостановить выполнение? как получить фидбек и передать прямо в функцию? как понять, что он получен?), затем продолжить функцию.

Условно говоря:

```
openIfWrong(array){ 
array.forEach((item, i)=> {
if(item==2) 
   this.modal.open();
 <....> 
);}
```

И после того, как окно было открыто, мне нужно дождаться фидбека от пользователя, и только после получения оного функция должна продолжиться.

На данный момент функция, из которой вызывается окно, продолжает работать.

Будучи новичком в реакте, не могу придумать, как это сделать, и не могу корректно сформулировать свой запрос гуглу.

Буду благодарна за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например в функции вызова окна предусмотреть указание callback-функции в качестве параметра. В окне при определенном действии вызвать callback-функцию в которой передать данные действий в окне. Схематичный пример:

```
open() {
    this.modal.open(this.onConfirm, this.onCancel);
}

onConfirm = (data) => {
    this.modal.close();
    this.someAction();
}

onCancel = () => {
    this.modal.close();
    this.anotherAction();
}
```

многое зависит от способов реализации модального окна и приложения, его вызывающего

Comment: Спасибо! Думала об этом, однако не очень понимаю, как это решает основную проблему: мне нужно приостановить текующую функцию до получения фидбека - и действия функции будут различаться в зависимости от ответа пользователя. 

Условно говоря: 

`openIfWrong(array){
array.forEach((item, i)=>
if(item==2)
 this.modal.open();

<....>
)
}`

И после того, как окно было открыто, мне нужно дождаться фидбека от пользователя, и только после получения оного функция должна продолжиться

Comment: нужно разделить действия. сначала общее действие. потом открытие окна. ответ пользователя помещается в data . в функции onConfirm проверяете if или switch ответ. В зависимости от ответа вызываете нужную функцию или прямо в onConfirm вызываете setState({answer: data.answer}) в зависимости от логики приложения

Comment: И об этом думала - но у меня идет итерация по массиву - и хотелось бы вернуться прямо в тоже самое место, из которого было открыто окно

Comment: Как вариант: отказываемся от перебора вообще. Делаем копию оригинального массива arrayClone, получаем первый элемент через arrayClone.shift(), анализируем его, вызываем модал, при закрытии в колбэке проверяем, если массив не пуст, то через shift() берем следующий элемент и так пока не закончится копия массива.